# How to optimize query with ORDER and LIMIT?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I have simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "reviews"
WHERE (reviews.branch_id = '12345678')
    AND (reviews.provider IN('first', 'second'))
    AND (is_hidden = FALSE)
ORDER BY reviews.date_created DESC
LIMIT 13
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    provider character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    branch_id bigint NOT NULL,
    text text NOT NULL,
    date_created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
);
CREATE INDEX reviews_provider_branch_id_date_created_idx ON reviews(provider, branch_id, date_created DESC) WHERE is_hidden=false;
```

Explain:

```
Limit  (cost=3278.96..3278.99 rows=13 width=1183) (actual time=15.657..15.668 rows=13 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=1834
->  Sort  (cost=3278.96..3283.32 rows=1743 width=1183) (actual time=15.654..15.665 rows=13 loops=1)
    Sort Key: date_created DESC
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 41kB
    Buffers: shared hit=1834
    ->  Index Scan using reviews_provider_branch_id_date_created_idx on reviews  (cost=0.43..3238.00 rows=1743 width=1183) (actual time=0.082..13.388 rows=1879 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (((provider)::text = ANY ('{first,second}'::text[])) AND (branch_id = '12345678'::bigint))
          Buffers: shared hit=1834
Planning time: 0.548 ms
Execution time: 15.791 ms
```

Without `ORDER`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..24.58 rows=13 width=1183) (actual time=0.047..0.088 rows=13 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=11
->  Index Scan using reviews_provider_branch_id_date_created_idx on reviews  (cost=0.43..3238.00 rows=1743 width=1183) (actual time=0.046..0.086 rows=13 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (((provider)::text = ANY ('{first,second}'::text[])) AND (branch_id = '12345678'::bigint))
    Buffers: shared hit=11
Planning time: 0.387 ms
Execution time: 0.135 ms
```

Is there any way to speed up this query?

Comment: Try to change the index to `(branch_id, provider, date_created DESC)` - with same `WHERE`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ not better: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Gl2Q

Comment: How does the execution plan without `order by` look like?

Comment: While the relative performance is indeed a lot better without the order by, I think 15 milliseconds are still acceptable. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: Please also add the `CREATE TABLE` script in the question, so w eknow the types of columns, constraints, etc. Why you use quotes `branch_id = '12345678'`  when branch_id is bigint?

Comment: A better index would be on `(branch_id, date_created, provider)`.  That way you get the selectivity of the branch_id, and the order for date_created, combined.  No sorting needed.

Comment: @jjanes It works! Please post your comment as an answer. Execution time is 0.180 ms. And index on `provider` is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the records under `branch_id = '12345678'` and each of the two providers are sorted in the order you want, they aren't in a sorted order once they've been pulled out (because you've got two sets that are pushed together).

You might get an improved sort if you pulled the top 13 records for the branch_id and each of the providers separately. These should already be in the order you want. Then, `UNION ALL` the two result sets and grab the top thirteen from that. Since they're already sorted in the right order, the engine may realize that and do something faster than a HEAP SORT.

NOTE: Depending on the total number of rows involved, the simple expedient of grabbing the top 13 rows for each branch and provider may speed things up tremendously, in that the heap sort has to sort through all the possible matches to find the top 13, whereas we've limited the possible row count to 26 at most.

Of course, this doesn't scale well. If the number of branches and providers in the query is ultimately variable, then you would either need to write a new version of the query each time the number of either of those changed, or build some really hairy dynamic SQL. If that's the case, then trying to further limit the pool of candidate rows should help; consider putting some sort of date range into the query.

UPDATE: [joanolo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/112361/joanolo) kindly put together the actual code for this, with a data sample of 900 records; here's the [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0bba7b385ac546bc813200ffeb936c79) link. It confirmed that the engine did pick something other than a heap sort - specifically, a quicksort. However, as joanolo notes, you need a reasonably large number of records for this to make a difference; with 900, it's faster, but not that much.

Comment: A practical simulation of this scenario can be found [at dbfiddle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0bba7b385ac546bc813200ffeb936c79). It must be said that this approach is only meaningful if the number of rows that would be returned by the query withouth the LIMIT 13 is far bigger than 13. In the simulated scenario, it is about 900).

Comment: Great idea! Execution time is 0.673 ms. Thank you!